# Returning Data from 1 Field with 2 Different Types without Repeating Lines, How?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am doing a large extract from a database for a customer and am running into an issue with one piece of their request. This is being done in MYSQL.

Currently, phone numbers are stored in a single field with a secondary field indicating what type of phone number it is (Home or Work), meaning that there may be multiple phone records for the same identity. This request is asking for all related phone numbers to be on 1 single line, so `Name, Address, Home Phone, Work Phone`

I'm having issues getting this data on one line, I've tried an `IF` statement:

```
SELECT Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, 
IF(a.phone_number_type_id = '1',Phone_Number, '')AS Primary_Number,
IF(a.phone_number_type_id = '3',Phone_Number,'')AS Secondary_Number
```

This gave an entry for each phone number, so some had 2 lines. CASE statement attempts haven't yielded any results. My SQL is mediocre at best, so, I am looking for help here, if this is even possible. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: SELECT  Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip FROM TABLENAME
 WHERE phone_number_type_id = '1' OR phone_number_type_id = '3' to get started .. it wont name them primary and secondary but we can work that out after.

Comment: You want to LEFT OUTER JOIN to this table multiple times, once for each type of phone number, specifying in the ON clause the phone_number_type_id you want for that join. If you can share your table schema and some sample data. we can help write that

Comment: here is a good citation on JOINs and how to use them, like JNevill mentioned, you sort of need to do TWO selects and JOIN them into one to get the results you want, but my suggestion was just to get your started.  Here is the link to learn more about JOINS
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_join.asp